# trying to delete items and save in sharedprefs

Tags: android

so my code basically when you press the FAB in the bottom corner, a view box, textview, spinner, edittext and checkbox appear. You can add as many of these set elements as many times.

I added shared prefs to my code so that when the user goes back to the main activity then back to the create activity, those items still stay. That works fine

but I have a functionality when the user presses the view box, that set of elements is deleted (that view box, the spinner, edittext, textview, checkbox with it).

so when I press it now, it deletes, then I go to the mainactivity screen then back to the create screen but ***those set element are still there? when they were suppose to be deleted?*** how to fix this?

create.java

```
public class create extends AppCompatActivity {


    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    private ArrayList<SearchableSpinner> mSpinners;
    private List<AppCompatButton> mButtons = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<CheckBox> mCheckboxes = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<TextView> mTextviews = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<EditText> mEdittexts = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<View> mViews = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<String, String> numberItemValues = new HashMap<>();
    private Spinner spinner;
    private TextView textview;
    private CheckBox checkbox;
    List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    LinearLayout verticallayout,horizontalLayout;
    public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        findViewById(R.id.my_linearLayout).requestFocus();

        verticallayout = findViewById(R.id.verticalLayout); //got





        //Arrays
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(String.valueOf(mSpinners)); // add you selected item
        mSpinners = new ArrayList<>();




        //Initializing Variables Here
        mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_linearLayout);
        //verticallayout = findViewById(R.id.verticalLayout);
        textview = findViewById(R.id.textview);
        checkbox = findViewById(R.id.checkbox);








        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray2 = new JSONArray(prefs.getString("key", null));
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray2.length(); i++) {



                final Spinner spinner = makeSpinner();
                mLinearLayout.addView(spinner);
                mSpinners.add((SearchableSpinner) spinner);


                final View newView = makeView();
                //Add a new view
                mLinearLayout.addView(newView);
                mViews.add(newView);


                final EditText newEdittext = makeEdittext();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newEdittext);
                mEdittexts.add(newEdittext);



                final CheckBox newCheckbox = makeCheckbox();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newCheckbox);

                //TODO add checkbox to your list
                mCheckboxes.add(newCheckbox);


                final TextView newTextview = makeTextview();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newTextview);
                mTextviews.add(newTextview);



                //TODO Add the spinner on item selected listener to get selected items
                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                        String currentItem = itemList.get(position);
                        String aisleNumber = numberItemValues.get(currentItem);
                        //TODO you can use the above aisle number to add to your text view
                        //mTextviews.get(mTextviews.size() -1).setText(aisleNumber);
                        newTextview.setText(aisleNumber);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                        //  do nothing
                    }
                });

                final int listSize = mViews.size();

                //TODO DELETIN ITEM
                newView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    //start
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        //when the 'new button' is pressed, alert shows if you are sure you want to delete the item or not.

                        final View.OnClickListener context = this;


                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(create.this);


                        // set title
                        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete Item");

                        // set dialog message
                        alertDialogBuilder
                                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, close
                                        // current activity


                                        if (listSize > 0) {

                                            mCheckboxes.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mSpinners.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mViews.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mTextviews.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mEdittexts.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }


                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        // show it
                        alertDialog.show();


                    }
                });





                int positionOfSpinner = (int) jsonArray2.get(i);
                spinner.setSelection(positionOfSpinner);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //end of shared pref  code








        //TODO FAB BUTTON
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =
                (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);


        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);



                // Handle ze click.
                final Spinner spinner = makeSpinner();
                mLinearLayout.addView(spinner);
                mSpinners.add((SearchableSpinner) spinner);



                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) spinner.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.setMargins(5, 100, 10, 0); //top 70

                Resources resources = getResources();
                DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();

                layoutParams.height = (int) (70 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)); //80
                layoutParams.width = (int) (240 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)); //240
                spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                final View newView = makeView();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newView);
                mViews.add(newView);


                final EditText newEdittext = makeEdittext();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newEdittext);
                mEdittexts.add(newEdittext);

                final int listSize = mViews.size();

                //code for deleting the said item.



                newView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    //start
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        //when the 'new button' is pressed, alert shows if you are sure you want to delete the item or not.

                        final View.OnClickListener context = this;


                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(create.this);


                        // set title
                        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete Item");

                        // set dialog message
                        alertDialogBuilder
                                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, close
                                        // current activity


                                        if (listSize > 0) {

                                            mCheckboxes.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mSpinners.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                           // mSpinners.remove(listSize - 1);
                                            mViews.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mTextviews.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mEdittexts.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        // show it
                        alertDialog.show();


                    }
                });

                //Add a new checkbox
                final CheckBox newCheckbox = makeCheckbox();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newCheckbox);

                //TODO add checkbox to your list
                mCheckboxes.add(newCheckbox);


                final TextView newTextview = makeTextview();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newTextview);
                mTextviews.add(newTextview);

                //TODO Add the spinner on item selected listener to get selected items
                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                        String currentItem = itemList.get(position);
                        String aisleNumber = numberItemValues.get(currentItem);
                        //TODO you can use the above aisle number to add to your text view
                        //mTextviews.get(mTextviews.size() -1).setText(aisleNumber);
                        newTextview.setText(aisleNumber);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                        //  code here, do nothing
                    }

                });


            }
        });

    }



















    //TODO OVERFLOW MENU
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.create_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            /*Intent startSettingsActivity = new Intent(this, AppCompatPreferenceActivity.class);
            startActivity(startSettingsActivity);
            //start the settings activity here.*/

            startActivity(new Intent(create.this, settings.class));





            return true;
        }


        else if (id == R.id.action_delete) {
            //code to delete list here.

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "List removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }


        else if (id ==R.id.action_help)  {


            // setup the alert builder
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Help");
            builder.setMessage("To use this app, first go to Create your Shopping List.\n" +
                    "Here, you can add items to your list. Once you have added all items, you can click the menu at the top right corner (or if it doesnt appear press your menu button beside your home button on your device, then click View your List.\n" +
                    "This will take you to the screen where you can view you shopping list with the items in aisle order to make your shop much easier.\n" +
                    "You can still add items at this point. Press the white background of each item to delete the item if you wish.");

            // add a button
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);

            // create and show the alert dialog
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();


            return true;

        }




        else if (id == R.id.action_gotoview) {


            //takes the size of the list of spinners, for reference
            ArrayList<Integer> spinnerList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < mSpinners.size(); i++) {
                spinnerList.add(mSpinners.get(i).getSelectedItemPosition());

            }
            Bundle newBundle = new Bundle();
            newBundle.putIntegerArrayList("arraylist", spinnerList);
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(create.this, viewscreen.class);
            newIntent.putExtra("extraBundle", newBundle);

            startActivity(newIntent);



            //code to go to view screen, aka intent
            return true;
        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }






    public void createRow(View view){

        createRow(); //got

    }


    private void createRow() { //got

        horizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams horizontalParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        horizontalLayout.setLayoutParams(horizontalParams);

        makeEdittext();
        makeCheckbox();
        makeView();

        verticallayout.addView(horizontalLayout);
    }







    //DUPLICATING ITEMS WHEN FAB IS PRESSED//
    private CheckBox makeCheckbox() {
        //Create new Checkbox
        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);

        // Setup layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        //setup relative layout for the positioning of the objects
        Resources resources = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (70 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)), (int) (240 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)));
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.textview);

        checkbox.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
        checkbox.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);



  /*      LinearLayout.LayoutParams checkParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        checkParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        checkParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

        checkbox.setLayoutParams(checkParams);
        horizontalLayout.addView(checkbox);*/


        return checkbox;
    }



    private TextView makeTextview() {
        //create new textview
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);

        //setup layout

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        textview.setTextSize(30);

        return textview;
    }



    private EditText makeEdittext() {
        //create new edittext
        EditText edittext = new EditText(this);

        //setup layout
        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70, 50); // Width , height
        edittext.setLayoutParams(lparams);


       /* LinearLayout.LayoutParams editParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        editParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);*/
        lparams.width = 70;
        lparams.height = 50;

        edittext.setLayoutParams(lparams);

/*
        edittext.setLayoutParams(editParams);
        horizontalLayout.addView(edittext);*/

        edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
        edittext.setHint("qty");

        return edittext;

    }



    private View makeView() {
        //create new View

        View view = new View(this);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100);
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50);


        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


        view.setClickable(true);

        //view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


        //setup layout

        return view;


    }














    private Spinner makeSpinner() {
        //opens csv
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
        CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
        //TODO I made this variable global, declared it at the very top of this file
        itemList = csvFile.read();

        //Create new spinner
        // SearchableSpinner spinner = (SearchableSpinner) new Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN);
        SearchableSpinner spinner = new SearchableSpinner(this);


        // Setup layout

    /*    LinearLayout.LayoutParams spinnerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        spinnerParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        spinnerParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

        Resources resources = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();

        spinnerParams.height = (int) (70 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)); //80
        spinnerParams.width = (int) (240 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)); //240

        spinner.setLayoutParams(spinnerParams);
        horizontalLayout.addView(spinner);*/

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);



        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, R.id.txtid, itemList);


        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Add it to your list of spinners so you can retrieve their data when you click the getSpinner button
        //mSpinners.add(spinner);
        return spinner;
    }



    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read() {

            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    //TODO I edited this part so that you'd add the values in our new hash map variable
                    numberItemValues.put(row[1], row[0]);
                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }


    //on stop, the things are saved into shared prefs
    @Override
    protected void onStop () {

        //public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < mSpinners.size(); i++) {
            jsonArray.put(mSpinners.get(i).getSelectedItemPosition());

        }

        editor.putString("key", jsonArray.toString());
        editor.apply();


        super.onStop();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you actually trying to do but as I got from your Question,
You want to delete the elements after doing some of your tasks. So, Now as you are using ArrayList<> to store the views, You can delete all of your views from ArrayList
like :

`arraylist.clear()`

and for your case :

```
private void clearViews(){
    mButtons.clear();
    mCheckboxes.clear();
    mViews.clear();
    mEdittexts.clear();
    mTextviews.clear();
    mSpinners.clear();
    //  more arrays you want to clear
}
```

Yes, it's true that you need to clear your shared preferences.
To work with shared pref., I have an example for you..

```
public class SharedMemory {
SharedPreferences prefs;
public SharedMemory(Context ctx) {prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences("SCREEN_SETTINGS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);}

void setValue(String value) {prefs.edit().putString("uUrl", value).apply();}
public String getValue() {return prefs.getString("uUrl", "");}

}
```

and you can add boolean, strings, and other data types in shared preferences.

you can call it like

```
// initialisation
SharedMemory shared = new SharedMemory(this);
```

to write data :

```
shared.setValue("your data");
```

to read data :

```
shared.getValue("your data");
```

to modify data :

```
shared.setValue("modfied data");
```

to remove data :

```
shared.setValue("");
```

Comment: but I only want the single viewbox, single edidttext, single spinner single textview and single checkbox deleted, not the whole array list?

Comment: You can just remove all views and then add only one view to your main root view

Answer (score 0):

You are not deleting the item from the `SharedPreferences` that's why it always returns. After deleting the item from the view, you should also remove the item from `SharedPreferences`. I see that your `SharedPreferences` contains one key that maps to a json array; when you delete from the view, get the json array from `SharedPreferences`, loop through it and remove the deleted item. Hope this is clear. The code will look like below:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(prefs.getString("key"));
        for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length; i++) {
            if(jArray.get(i).contains(mSpinners.get(listSize - 1).getSelectedItemPosition())){
                jArray.remove(i);
            }
        }
        //update the prefs
        editor.putString("key",jArray);
editor.apply();
```

Place this before the 'Item removed' Toast.

Comment: hmm okay but how do I delete from shared pref?

Comment: do you have an example of what this would look like : )

Comment: Give me a moment, let me get it for you

Comment: for this line                     jArray.remove(i);
 it says remove requires api level 19 but I have got it set to 16

Comment: also can't resolve symbol lengths or prefs?  and unhandled exception for 'get' in this line  if(jArray.get(i)

Comment: To resolve prefs, make it a global variable. to resolve length, change it to `length()`